# glassfish 4 server starts twice

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, jrebel

so i am using jsf 2.2 , primefaces 5.0, jrabel 6.0 agent
when I start Gf v4 server, I dont know why it starts twice
see **server log** from eclipse:

```
2014-12-29T19:52:44.398+0500|INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
2014-12-29T19:52:44.401+0500|INFO: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2014-12-29T19:52:44.910+0500|INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2014-12-29T19:52:44.940+0500|INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2014-12-29T19:52:44.948+0500|INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2014-12-29T19:52:46.023+0500|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 93ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,080]
2014-12-29T19:52:46.129+0500|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]
2014-12-29T19:52:46.140+0500|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4,848]
2014-12-29T19:52:46.481+0500|INFO: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2014-12-29T19:52:46.539+0500|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3,700]
2014-12-29T19:52:46.560+0500|INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2014-12-29T19:52:47.437+0500|INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [210]], State = [READY]
2014-12-29T19:52:47.439+0500|INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [107]], State = [READY]
2014-12-29T19:52:54.022+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:52:55.844+0500|SEVERE: SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23741889829347261660812437366387754385443431973861114865490414153884050331745811968523116847625570146592736935209718565296053386842135985534863157983128812774162998053673746470782252407673402238146869994438729551246768368782318393878374421033907597162218758024581735139682087126982809511479059100617027892880227587855877479432885604404402435662802390484099065871430585284534529627347717530352189612077130606642676951640071336717026459037542552927905851171460589361570392199748753414855675665635003335769915908187224347232807336022456537328962095005323382940080676931822787496212635993279098588863972868266229522169377
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Aug 14 19:50:00 PKT 1998,
               To: Thu Aug 15 04:59:00 PKT 2013]
  Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    01b6]
Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:5
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113763.1.2.1.3]
[]  ]
]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 0A 49 21 38 4C 9F DE   F8 C4 49 C7 71 71 91 9D  v.I!8L....I.qq..
]
]
]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 3A D4 18 5B DA B8 DE   21 1C E1 8E 09 E5 F1 68  A:..[...!......h
0010: 34 FF DE 96 F4 07 F5 A7   3C F3 AC 4A B1 9B FA 92  4.......<..J....
0020: FA 9B ED E6 32 21 AA 4A   76 C5 DC 4F 38 E5 DF D5  ....2!.Jv..O8...
0030: 86 E4 D5 C8 76 7D 98 D7   B1 CD 8F 4D B5 91 23 6C  ....v......M..#l
0040: 8B 8A EB EA 7C EF 14 94   C4 C6 F0 1F 4A 2D 32 71  ............J-2q
0050: 63 2B 63 91 26 02 09 B6   80 1D ED E2 CC B8 7F DB  c+c.&...........
0060: 87 63 C8 E1 D0 6C 26 B1   35 1D 40 66 10 1B CD 95  .c...l&.5.@f....
0070: 54 18 33 61 EC 13 4F DA   13 F7 99 AF 3E D0 CF 8E  T.3a..O.....>...
0080: A6 72 A2 B3 C3 05 9A C9   27 7D 92 CC 7E 52 8D B3  .r......'....R..
0090: AB 70 6D 9E 89 9F 4D EB   1A 75 C2 98 AA D5 02 16  .pm...M..u......
00A0: D7 0C 8A BF 25 E4 EB 2D   BC 98 E9 58 38 19 7C B9  ....%..-...X8...
00B0: 37 FE DB E2 99 08 73 06   C7 97 83 6A 7D 10 01 2F  7.....s....j.../
00C0: 32 B9 17 05 4A 65 E6 2F   CE BE 5E 53 A6 82 E9 9A  2...Je./..^S....
00D0: 53 0A 84 74 2D 83 CA C8   94 16 76 5F 94 61 28 F0  S..t-.....v_.a(.
00E0: 85 A7 39 BB D7 8B D9 A8   B2 13 1D 54 09 34 24 7D  ..9........T.4$.
00F0: 20 81 7D 66 7E A2 90 74   5C 10 C6 BD EC AB 1B C2   ..f...t\.......
]
2014-12-29T19:52:55.961+0500|INFO: 2014-12-29 19:52:55 JRebel: Directory 'D:\HescoApp repo\HescoApp\build\classes' will be monitored for changes.
2014-12-29T19:52:55.964+0500|INFO: 2014-12-29 19:52:55 JRebel: Directory 'D:\HescoApp repo\HescoApp\WebContent' will be monitored for changes.
2014-12-29T19:52:55.870+0500|INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
2014-12-29T19:52:56.053+0500|INFO: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
2014-12-29T19:52:56.060+0500|INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2014-12-29T19:52:56.222+0500|INFO: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
2014-12-29T19:52:57.133+0500|INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2014-12-29T19:52:57.148+0500|INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2014-12-29T19:52:57.156+0500|INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2014-12-29T19:52:57.268+0500|INFO: Created virtual server server
2014-12-29T19:52:57.272+0500|INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
2014-12-29T19:52:57.984+0500|INFO: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2014-12-29T19:52:57.985+0500|INFO: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2014-12-29T19:52:59.787+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references

2014-12-29T19:53:00.580+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references

2014-12-29T19:53:00.678+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:53:00.682+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:53:00.686+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:53:00.689+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:53:01.315+0500|INFO: WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1)
2014-12-29T19:53:03.735+0500|INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2014-12-29T19:53:06.795+0500|INFO: Adding singleton for WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
2014-12-29T19:53:07.986+0500|WARNING: Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2014-12-29T19:53:07.987+0500|WARNING: Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2014-12-29T19:53:10.458+0500|INFO: 2014-12-29 19:53:10 JRebel-Log4j: Monitoring Log4j configuration in 'file:/D:/HescoApp%20repo/HescoApp/build/classes/log4j.xml'.
2014-12-29T19:53:13.905+0500|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context '/HescoApp'
2014-12-29T19:53:19.760+0500|WARNING: JSF1025: [/HescoApp] Context initialization parameter 'facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS' is deprecated.  The option will still be configured, but please use 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS' in the future.
2014-12-29T19:53:19.761+0500|INFO: JSF1020: [/HescoApp] Configuration option 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS' RESET to ENABLED
2014-12-29T19:53:19.806+0500|INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
2014-12-29T19:53:19.826+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.app.startup.ConfigStartupServlet] application started!
2014-12-29T19:53:19.835+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetFinancialYearService] retrieveOpenedFinancialYearForProposal is invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:19.838+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: static block of Connection before try catch:
2014-12-29T19:53:19.839+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: static block of Connection
2014-12-29T19:53:19.839+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration class
2014-12-29T19:53:20.514+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration Object
2014-12-29T19:53:20.977+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration Service Registry builder
2014-12-29T19:53:21.109+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration Building Session Factory
2014-12-29T19:53:39.671+0500|INFO: Connection Established!
2014-12-29T19:53:40.163+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetfina0_.budget_financial_year_ID as budget1_32_, budgetfina0_.demands_financial_year_close_date as demands2_32_, budgetfina0_.demands_financial_year_open_date as demands3_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year as financial4_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_for_demands as financial5_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_for_proposals as financial6_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_from as financial7_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_to as financial8_32_, budgetfina0_.isActive as isActive32_, budgetfina0_.is_financial_year as is10_32_, budgetfina0_.proposals_financial_year_close_date as proposals11_32_, budgetfina0_.proposals_financial_year_open_date as proposals12_32_ from hesco.budget_financial_year budgetfina0_ where budgetfina0_.financial_year_for_proposals=1 and budgetfina0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:53:41.125+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetFinancialYearService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:41.149+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAllCircles invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:41.163+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select circle0_.circle_ID as circle1_10_, circle0_.circle_Name as circle2_10_, circle0_.circle_remarks as circle3_10_, circle0_.city_ID as city5_10_, circle0_.company_ID as company6_10_, circle0_.isActive as isActive10_ from hesco.circle circle0_ where circle0_.isActive=1 order by circle0_.circle_ID asc
2014-12-29T19:53:41.271+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:41.272+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAllCompanies invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:41.281+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select company0_.company_ID as company1_8_, company0_.company_name as company2_8_, company0_.company_remarks as company3_8_, company0_.isActive as isActive8_ from hesco.company company0_ where company0_.isActive=1 order by company0_.company_ID asc
2014-12-29T19:53:41.737+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:41.738+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveOprRo invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:41.750+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetoprr0_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget1_36_, budgetoprr0_.isActive as isActive36_, budgetoprr0_.opr_ro_name as opr3_36_ from hesco.budget_opr_ro budgetoprr0_ where budgetoprr0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:53:41.923+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:41.923+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAllFormationsByBudgetOprRoId invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:41.939+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetform0_.budget_formation_ID as budget1_33_0_, budgetoprr1_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget1_36_1_, budgetform0_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget4_33_0_, budgetform0_.circle_ID as circle5_33_0_, budgetform0_.formation_name as formation2_33_0_, budgetform0_.isActive as isActive33_0_, budgetoprr1_.isActive as isActive36_1_, budgetoprr1_.opr_ro_name as opr3_36_1_ from hesco.budget_formations budgetform0_ inner join hesco.budget_opr_ro budgetoprr1_ on budgetform0_.budget_opr_ro_ID=budgetoprr1_.budget_opr_ro_ID where budgetoprr1_.isActive=1 and budgetform0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:53:42.033+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:42.045+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetmain0_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget1_34_, budgetmain0_.budget_maintenance_establishment_ID as budget6_34_, budgetmain0_.company_ID as company7_34_, budgetmain0_.isActive as isActive34_, budgetmain0_.main_head_of_account_code as main3_34_, budgetmain0_.main_head_of_account_name as main4_34_, budgetmain0_.main_head_of_account_remarks as main5_34_, budgetmain0_.section_ID as section8_34_ from hesco.budget_main_head_of_accounts budgetmain0_ where budgetmain0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:53:42.150+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetHeadOfAccountsService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:42.161+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetsubh0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget1_39_, budgetsubh0_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget8_39_, budgetsubh0_.date as date39_, budgetsubh0_.isActive as isActive39_, budgetsubh0_.status as status39_, budgetsubh0_.sub_head_of_account_code as sub5_39_, budgetsubh0_.sub_head_of_account_name as sub6_39_, budgetsubh0_.sub_head_of_account_remarks as sub7_39_, budgetsubh0_.user_ID as user9_39_ from hesco.budget_sub_head_of_accounts budgetsubh0_ where budgetsubh0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:53:42.232+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetHeadOfAccountsService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:42.234+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetAllocatedToHescoService] retrieveAllocatedBudgetToHesco is invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:42.273+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetallo0_.budget_allocated_to_hesco_ID as budget1_29_0_, budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget1_39_1_, budgetfina2_.budget_financial_year_ID as budget1_32_2_, company3_.company_ID as company1_8_3_, budgetallo0_.after_reservation_date as after2_29_0_, budgetallo0_.allocated_budget as allocated3_29_0_, budgetallo0_.allocated_date as allocated4_29_0_, budgetallo0_.balance_budget as balance5_29_0_, budgetallo0_.budget_financial_year_ID as budget15_29_0_, budgetallo0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget16_29_0_, budgetallo0_.company_ID as company17_29_0_, budgetallo0_.final_budget_after_reservation as final6_29_0_, budgetallo0_.isActive as isActive29_0_, budgetallo0_.isApproved as isApproved29_0_, budgetallo0_.isLock as isLock29_0_, budgetallo0_.isapproved_after_reservation_of_budget as isapproved10_29_0_, budgetallo0_.islock_after_reservation_of_budget as islock11_29_0_, budgetallo0_.reservation_basis as reserva12_29_0_, budgetallo0_.reservation_variance as reserva13_29_0_, budgetallo0_.reserved_budget_by_head_of_accounts as reserved14_29_0_, budgetsubh1_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget8_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.date as date39_1_, budgetsubh1_.isActive as isActive39_1_, budgetsubh1_.status as status39_1_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_code as sub5_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_name as sub6_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_remarks as sub7_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.user_ID as user9_39_1_, budgetfina2_.demands_financial_year_close_date as demands2_32_2_, budgetfina2_.demands_financial_year_open_date as demands3_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year as financial4_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_for_demands as financial5_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_for_proposals as financial6_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_from as financial7_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_to as financial8_32_2_, budgetfina2_.isActive as isActive32_2_, budgetfina2_.is_financial_year as is10_32_2_, budgetfina2_.proposals_financial_year_close_date as proposals11_32_2_, budgetfina2_.proposals_financial_year_open_date as proposals12_32_2_, company3_.company_name as company2_8_3_, company3_.company_remarks as company3_8_3_, company3_.isActive as isActive8_3_ from hesco.budget_allocated_to_hesco budgetallo0_ cross join hesco.budget_sub_head_of_accounts budgetsubh1_ cross join hesco.budget_financial_year budgetfina2_ cross join hesco.company company3_ where budgetallo0_.budget_financial_year_ID=budgetfina2_.budget_financial_year_ID and budgetallo0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID=budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID and budgetallo0_.company_ID=company3_.company_ID and budgetallo0_.isLock=1 and budgetallo0_.isActive=1 and budgetallo0_.isApproved=1 order by budgetallo0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID
2014-12-29T19:53:42.366+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetAllocatedToHescoService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:42.366+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAssignedSubHeadOfAccounts invoking
2014-12-29T19:53:42.383+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget1_39_0_, budgetform2_.budget_formation_ID as budget1_33_1_, budgetsubh1_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget8_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.date as date39_0_, budgetsubh1_.isActive as isActive39_0_, budgetsubh1_.status as status39_0_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_code as sub5_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_name as sub6_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_remarks as sub7_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.user_ID as user9_39_0_, budgetform2_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget4_33_1_, budgetform2_.circle_ID as circle5_33_1_, budgetform2_.formation_name as formation2_33_1_, budgetform2_.isActive as isActive33_1_ from hesco.budget_assigned_sub_head_of_accounts budgetassi0_ cross join hesco.budget_sub_head_of_accounts budgetsubh1_ cross join hesco.budget_formations budgetform2_ where budgetassi0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID=budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID and budgetassi0_.budget_formation_ID=budgetform2_.budget_formation_ID and budgetassi0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:53:42.456+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:53:43.244+0500|INFO: [Authentication Filter] : new init Method
2014-12-29T19:53:43.254+0500|INFO: Loading application [HescoApp] at [/HescoApp]
2014-12-29T19:53:43.258+0500|INFO: Loading application HescoApp done in 56,315 ms
2014-12-29T19:53:43.336+0500|INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (19,842ms), startup services(59,578ms), total(79,420ms)
2014-12-29T19:53:45.528+0500|INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
2014-12-29T19:53:45.609+0500|INFO: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@6bfd62fa as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@2d70083c.
2014-12-29T19:53:48.942+0500|INFO: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://mohsin:8686/jndi/rmi://mohsin:8686/jmxrmi
2014-12-29T19:53:50.666+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.app.startup.ConfigStartupServlet] application destroyed!
2014-12-29T19:53:50.737+0500|WARNING: The web application [/HescoApp] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2014-12-29T19:53:57.937+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:53:58.746+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references

2014-12-29T19:53:59.015+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:53:59.017+0500|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-12-29T19:54:00.039+0500|INFO: Adding singleton for WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
2014-12-29T19:54:02.240+0500|INFO: 2014-12-29 19:54:02 JRebel-Log4j: Monitoring Log4j configuration in 'file:/D:/HescoApp%20repo/HescoApp/build/classes/log4j.xml'.
2014-12-29T19:54:03.216+0500|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context '/HescoApp'
2014-12-29T19:54:04.885+0500|WARNING: JSF1025: [/HescoApp] Context initialization parameter 'facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS' is deprecated.  The option will still be configured, but please use 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS' in the future.
2014-12-29T19:54:04.886+0500|INFO: JSF1020: [/HescoApp] Configuration option 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS' RESET to ENABLED
2014-12-29T19:54:04.889+0500|INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
2014-12-29T19:54:04.893+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.app.startup.ConfigStartupServlet] application started!
2014-12-29T19:54:04.900+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetFinancialYearService] retrieveOpenedFinancialYearForProposal is invoking
2014-12-29T19:54:04.904+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: static block of Connection before try catch:
2014-12-29T19:54:04.904+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: static block of Connection
2014-12-29T19:54:04.904+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration class
2014-12-29T19:54:05.383+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration Object
2014-12-29T19:54:05.672+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration Service Registry builder
2014-12-29T19:54:05.800+0500|INFO: [DatabaseManager]: Configuration Building Session Factory
2014-12-29T19:54:08.717+0500|INFO: Connection Established!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.104+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetfina0_.budget_financial_year_ID as budget1_32_, budgetfina0_.demands_financial_year_close_date as demands2_32_, budgetfina0_.demands_financial_year_open_date as demands3_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year as financial4_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_for_demands as financial5_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_for_proposals as financial6_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_from as financial7_32_, budgetfina0_.financial_year_to as financial8_32_, budgetfina0_.isActive as 
2014-12-29T19:54:09.254+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.254+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAllCompanies invoking
2014-12-29T19:54:09.263+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select company0_.company_ID as company1_8_, company0_.company_name as company2_8_, company0_.company_remarks as company3_8_, company0_.isActive as isActive8_ from hesco.company company0_ where company0_.isActive=1 order by company0_.company_ID asc
2014-12-29T19:54:09.268+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.268+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveOprRo invoking
2014-12-29T19:54:09.275+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetoprr0_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget1_36_, budgetoprr0_.isActive as isActive36_, budgetoprr0_.opr_ro_name as opr3_36_ from hesco.budget_opr_ro budgetoprr0_ where budgetoprr0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:54:09.278+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.279+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAllFormationsByBudgetOprRoId invoking
2014-12-29T19:54:09.294+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetform0_.budget_formation_ID as budget1_33_0_, budgetoprr1_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget1_36_1_, budgetform0_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget4_33_0_, budgetform0_.circle_ID as circle5_33_0_, budgetform0_.formation_name as formation2_33_0_, budgetform0_.isActive as isActive33_0_, budgetoprr1_.isActive as isActive36_1_, budgetoprr1_.opr_ro_name as opr3_36_1_ from hesco.budget_formations budgetform0_ inner join hesco.budget_opr_ro budgetoprr1_ on budgetform0_.budget_opr_ro_ID=budgetoprr1_.budget_opr_ro_ID where budgetoprr1_.isActive=1 and budgetform0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:54:09.326+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.336+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetmain0_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget1_34_, budgetmain0_.budget_maintenance_establishment_ID as budget6_34_, budgetmain0_.company_ID as company7_34_, budgetmain0_.isActive as isActive34_, budgetmain0_.main_head_of_account_code as main3_34_, budgetmain0_.main_head_of_account_name as main4_34_, budgetmain0_.main_head_of_account_remarks as main5_34_, budgetmain0_.section_ID as section8_34_ from hesco.budget_main_head_of_accounts budgetmain0_ where budgetmain0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:54:09.375+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetHeadOfAccountsService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.384+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetsubh0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget1_39_, budgetsubh0_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget8_39_, budgetsubh0_.date as date39_, budgetsubh0_.isActive as isActive39_, budgetsubh0_.status as status39_, budgetsubh0_.sub_head_of_account_code as sub5_39_, budgetsubh0_.sub_head_of_account_name as sub6_39_, budgetsubh0_.sub_head_of_account_remarks as sub7_39_, budgetsubh0_.user_ID as user9_39_ from hesco.budget_sub_head_of_accounts budgetsubh0_ where budgetsubh0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:54:09.421+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetHeadOfAccountsService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.424+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetAllocatedToHescoService] retrieveAllocatedBudgetToHesco is invoking
2014-12-29T19:54:09.462+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetallo0_.budget_allocated_to_hesco_ID as budget1_29_0_, budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget1_39_1_, budgetfina2_.budget_financial_year_ID as budget1_32_2_, company3_.company_ID as company1_8_3_, budgetallo0_.after_reservation_date as after2_29_0_, budgetallo0_.allocated_budget as allocated3_29_0_, budgetallo0_.allocated_date as allocated4_29_0_, budgetallo0_.balance_budget as balance5_29_0_, budgetallo0_.budget_financial_year_ID as budget15_29_0_, budg, budgetsubh1_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget8_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.date as date39_1_, budgetsubh1_.isActive as isActive39_1_, budgetsubh1_.status as status39_1_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_code as sub5_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_name as sub6_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_remarks as sub7_39_1_, budgetsubh1_.user_ID as user9_39_1_, budgetfina2_.demands_financial_year_close_date as demands2_32_2_, budgetfina2_.demands_financial_year_open_date as demands3_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year as financial4_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_for_demands as financial5_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_for_proposals as financial6_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_from as financial7_32_2_, budgetfina2_.financial_year_to as financial8_32_2_, budgetfina2_.isActive as isActive32_2_, budgetfina2_.is_financial_year as is10_32_2_, [com.hesco.repository.fd.section.budget.service.BudgetAllocatedToHescoService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:09.508+0500|INFO: INFO  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] retrieveAssignedSubHeadOfAccounts invoking
2014-12-29T19:54:09.525+0500|INFO: Hibernate: select budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID as budget1_39_0_, budgetform2_.budget_formation_ID as budget1_33_1_, budgetsubh1_.budget_main_head_of_account_ID as budget8_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.date as date39_0_, budgetsubh1_.isActive as isActive39_0_, budgetsubh1_.status as status39_0_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_code as sub5_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_name as sub6_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.sub_head_of_account_remarks as sub7_39_0_, budgetsubh1_.user_ID as user9_39_0_, budgetform2_.budget_opr_ro_ID as budget4_33_1_, budgetform2_.circle_ID as circle5_33_1_, budgetform2_.formation_name as formation2_33_1_, budgetform2_.isActive as isActive33_1_ from hesco.budget_assigned_sub_head_of_accounts budgetassi0_ cross join hesco.budget_sub_head_of_accounts budgetsubh1_ cross join hesco.budget_formations budgetform2_ where budgetassi0_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID=budgetsubh1_.budget_sub_head_of_account_ID and budgetassi0_.budget_formation_ID=budgetform2_.budget_formation_ID and budgetassi0_.isActive=1
2014-12-29T19:54:09.540+0500|INFO: WARN  [com.hesco.repository.common.generalinformation.service.GeneralInformationService] Connection Closed!
2014-12-29T19:54:10.146+0500|INFO: [Authentication Filter] : new init Method
2014-12-29T19:54:10.154+0500|INFO: Loading application [HescoApp] at [/HescoApp]
2014-12-29T19:54:10.258+0500|INFO: HescoApp was successfully deployed in 19,696 milliseconds.
```

Comment: The server isn't started twices, it is just the application which is deployed twice. The second deployment overwrites the first one but this normally shouldn't be a problem. I guess JRebel may be the cause of this behaviour. You may try the same without JRebel.

Comment: @unwichtich yes i was also thinking, this is just because of jrabel

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where glassfish is starting twice. What I see is the grizzly framework which is part of glassfish emitting log messages about binding to the same ports as the glassfish http listener.

Are you facing any issues?

Comment: then why my application is establishing connection to db, twice? see this logs `[DatabaseManager]: static block of Connection before try catch:` gf log twice!